# How to find unclosed I/O resources in Java?

Tags: java, resources, io, static-analysis

Many I/O resources in Java such as InputStream and OutputStream need to be closed when they are finished with, as discussed [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/202922/Performance/java/Unclosed-File-input-stream).

How can I search my project for places where such resources are not being closed, e.g. this kind of error:

```
private void readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    int nextByte = in.read();
    while (nextByte != -1) {
        // Do something with the byte here
        // ...
        // Read the next byte
        nextByte = in.read();
    }
    // Oops! Not closing the InputStream
}
```

I've tried some static analysis tools such as PMD and FindBugs, but they don't flag the above code as being wrong.

Comment: FindBugs seems to be able to detect this, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570820/findbugs-may-fail-to-close-stream-is-this-valid-in-case-of-inputstream

Comment: Sounds like you need to adjust which rules FindBugs checks

Answer (score 6):

It's probably matter of **setting** - I ran FindBugs through my IDE plugin and it reported OS_OPEN_STREAM.

Comment: Can you elaborate what setting need to be done in the FindBugs? IMO, this should have been enabled by default, given the side effects of application crash when it ran out of ulimit.

Answer (score 6):

If FindBugs with modified rules doesn't work for you, another slower approach is heap analysis. VisualVM allows you to query all objects of a specific type that are open at any given time within a heap dump using OQL. You could then check for streams open to files that shouldn't be accessed at that point in the program.

Running it is as simple as:

```
%>jvisualvm
```

Choose the running process. Choose option save heap dump (or something to that effect), open the heap dump and look at class instances for file streams in the browser, or query for them.

Comment: I think this method does not work if the associated stream only leaves memory allocation on the native memory (vm_allocate) and you want to track down those streams. They already have been garbage collected (so they don't show up on the heap), but they did not clean up the native memory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312229/where-did-jvisualvm-go

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7, they added a feature of using closable resources in current scope (so called try-with-resources), such as:

```java
public void someMethod() {
    try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        //do something here
    } // the stream is closed here
}
```

In older versions, the common technique is using try-catch-finally chain.

Comment: OK, so my question in other words is in Java 6 or earlier, how can I find instances of not using the "try then finally close" technique?

Comment: Google says that FindBugs is able to find such kind of bugs