# Where did jvisualvm go?

Tags: java, macos

I am running Mac OSX Snow Leopard.

I've always updated Java using the regular Software Update features of Mac OSX.

I've used the Java `jvisualvm` tool in the past with great success.

This morning I typed `jvisualvm` into the command line as I often do.  I got the following error:

```
 $ jvisualvm
 Unable to locate an executable at "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm" (-1)
```

All of the other Java tools (`java`, `javac`, `jps`, etc.) work just fine.

`/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin` indeed does not contain `jvisualvm` (all of a sudden).

`/usr/libexec/java_home` yields:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

WTF?

Comment: Try /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/jvisualvm

Comment: No dice: ` /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/jvisualvm
Unable to locate an executable at "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm" (-1)`

Comment: @LairdNelson same here :( this is very weird. I downloaded the VisualVM by hand and it works, sort of. It does not connect to any app to profile for example.

Comment: You know I'm having a similar problem.  I think the root cause is some VisualVM but on OS X 10.8.3 + JDK7.  VisualVM fires up but complains "attach: task_for_pid(330) failed (5)" on the PID that is my eclipse.  If I remove eclipse and try again, it succeeds in finding the running java processes on Local.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Seems like a mixup of links; the /usr/bin/jvisualvm symlink points to something that does not exist (as people pointed out above). Apparently the jvisualvm executable (stub) exists and the way to fix this for now is to execute:

```
cd /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

sudo ln -s /System/Library/Java/Support/VisualVM.bundle/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm .
```

This requires sudo privileges and creates the missing symlink, pointing to the VisualVM bundle. No idea why it happened but upgrading to latest XCode 4.5.2 did not fix this for me automatically. I am running MacOS X 10.7.5 and java 1.6.0_37

Comment: Thanks for your input; I'll try this out shortly and give you the answer if it works.

Comment: This approach no longer works (at least in Mountain Lion). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13690431/1395668

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer to an answer that instructs the reader to download the JVisualVM dmg.

Comment: Path in Mac Sierra 10.12.1 is : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm

Answer (score 28):

It seems the supporting bundle got removed upon update.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4474992?start=0&tstart=0

Download the bundle to use as a workaround.
http://visualvm.java.net/download.html

**EDIT:**

Use this download link: https://java.net/projects/visualvm/downloads/download/release132/VisualVM_132.d‌​mg

Comment: The latest .dmg bundle (1.3.7) doesn't seem to work with the latest stock Java-6 on OSX 10.9.1. It complains:     `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/VisualVM.app`

Comment: replying to myself: version 1.3.5 still works on Mavericks. Download it from [https://java.net/projects/visualvm/downloads/download/release132/VisualVM_132.dmg](https://java.net/projects/visualvm/downloads/download/release132/VisualVM_132.dmg)   and run the update to download the latest engine.

Answer (score 22):

I downloaded the visualvm ([.dmg from java.net](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html)) and that works for me on my Mountain Lion.

[image]

[image: screen shot of VisualVM Download page with specific option for Mac OS X application]

Comment: Virtualvm is actually more visually appealing than jconsole and offers more capability if you want to do profiling.

Answer (score 15):

For **JDK 9+**  users

> Starting with JDK 9, Visual VM will not be included with Oracle JDK. Developers who would like to use Visual VM with Oracle JDK 9 or later can get it from the Visual VM open source project site.

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using NetBeans, another workaround is to use its profiler. In version 7.3:

- Start the Java application from the command line, desktop or [javawebstart](/questions/tagged/javawebstart).
- In NetBeans, choose `Profile > Attach Profiler`.
- Select `Attach to: <external Application>`.
- Specify the desired analysis options.
- Click the `Attach` button.
- Choose the target application.

[image: Profiler dialog]

Answer (score 3):

VisualVM is also available as a standalone application. you can install it from 
https://visualvm.github.io/download.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

The Visual VM binary path for JDK 1.8 in macOS Mojave is

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm
```

Basically,

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<JDK_DIR>/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only run the .app version of JVisualVM on my mountain lion MBP

```
open /usr/share/java/Tools/Java\ VisualVM.app
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation on why?

Comment: That also does not work for me; attempting to open it just briefly launches...launches nothing, really.  Investigating the underlying `jvisualvm` symlink I see that it points back to the same failed location: `s -al /usr/share/java/Tools/Java\ VisualVM.app/Contents/MacOS/jvisualvm 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  97 Aug  2  2010 /usr/share/java/Tools/Java VisualVM.app/Contents/MacOS/jvisualvm -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/VisualVM.bundle/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm`

Comment: I'm not sure why, I guess someone at apple got confused by all the links and deleted something.

Comment: @Laird, my .app file looks different: `ls /usr/share/java/Tools/Java\ VisualVM.app/Contents/MacOS
JavaApplicationStub`
but following the dots led me to this executable which, again, works for me from command line. 
`/System/Library/Java/Support/VisualVM.bundle/Contents/Home/bin/jvisualvm`
for the record
`java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"`

Comment: WFM. Before I found this answer I found a man page on the Apple developer site (http://bit.ly/T0689b) that said jvisualvm was part of the Xcode command-line tools, so I launched Xcode and did an update of the Command Line Tools (Preferences -> Downloads -> Command Line Tools -> Update). Perhaps that is required?

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes it is very simple... you need to install visualvm via

```
sudo apt-get install visualvm
```

For locating the files, use

```
dpkg -L visualvm
```

Comment: Argh, sorry, I somehow overlooked that he was using a Mac. >_<

Comment: Please note as well that the program is normally already installed with the JDK.