# How to prevent resize lag in swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In every project I make in swing, no matter how simple, there is always a lag when resizing the window. The components inside don't resize at the same rate, leading to a non-native awkward looking effect.

This is an image of a JFrame mid-resize. I created a project with a JFrame and a simple JPanel added to the content pane with the background color grey. (Border Layout center):

[image]

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355916/java-jcomponent-lag-on-resize