# How can I find all instances and objects in my code that are not closed?

Tags: java, try-with-resources, autocloseable

My team has quite a huge amount of code. Recently I have found some objects that weren't closed properly.
How can i find all the instances that are not closed or not inside a `try-with-resources` block?
Some objects like `Statement`, `ResultSet` are not showing warning messages for it, even.

Is there an extension tool for showing all this occurrences?
I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: AFAIK try with resources promises to close resources, so this should not be happening there.  But what about the old school `try`-`catch` blocks, do you have any of those as well?

Comment: @Tim TWR only guarantees to close the "named" resources. For example, `try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("..."))) {}`, only the `BufferedReader` is guaranteed to be closed. The FIS and ISR might not be, if construction of the BR fails.

Comment: So then any resource block could have a problem, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343158/how-to-find-unclosed-i-o-resources-in-java.

Comment: As one of possible solutions in IDEA: show hierarchy of `Closeable` interface (default - ctrl+H) and find usages (alt+F7) of each class from hierarchy in project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static code analysis tools like [Sonar](https://www.sonarqube.org/) should find all those occurrences and warn you about them.
[IDEA IntelliJ's inspection profiles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/code-inspection.html) also includes some rules for that (*Settings > Editor > Inspections > Java > Resource management issues*, or just filter by "close" inside Inspections).

I see that you're using Eclipse. You can probably install [the FindBugs Eclipse plugin](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html), which includes a couple of rules to check if resources are properly closed.